# Can the default filename for :mksession be changed?

Tags: sessions

If `:mksession` or `vim -S` is used without a filename parameter a default file `Session.vim` is used. This can be very convenient.

I wonder if there is a way to change this default filename to something different (e.g. `.session.vim`?

My usecase would simply be to make this file a bit more unobtrusive when placed in a projects directory.

Comment: You can supply non-default filename parameter as you wish. But you can't change app default without recompiling it from source code. Is this what's your question about?

Comment: My question is about changing the app default.

Comment: A builtin command cannot be altered. Create your own command instead, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately it is relatively easy to compile vim to use a different name if desired: edit [`src/feature.h`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/df6e0e46c55c9c6d788f94482a8858c0f31391f4/src/feature.h#L750) to change

```c
#define SESSION_FILE    "Session.vim"
```

to whatever name you want. Then recompile as normal.

---

For the curious, I found this in my clone of the vim source with `git grep Session.vim '*[ch]'`.